# Accessing a subfolder of a Wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have a wordpress website installed in the root of my domain and it is up and running fine.  I want to install a shopping cart in a subfolder but it's giving me trouble.  I have a folder called "magento".  In that folder is a filed called downloader.php and index.php.

When I try to access the file, Wordpress was giving me a 404 error like it was thinking I meant it to look for a WP article.
I tried a different .htaccess file which changed it to a standard 500 error now.

I've googled for this and found tons of people with the same problem, but haven't found a solution that works.  I also checked the permissions and the folder is 777 and I changed the files to 777 as well but it still doesn't work.

The .htaccess file in the root (public_html) file simply shows

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /wp/index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I don't know anything about configuring .htaccess files but if anyone has any suggestions on how I can get this to work, that'd be great.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 5):

You can install an empty .htaccess file in the `magento` subdirectory. This [overrides](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/howto/htaccess.html#how) the Wordpress .htaccess file and allows to access the files in that directory.

Never change file permissions to `777`. This is dangerous, because it allows *anybody* to modify your files.